# How can I perfectly justify text in Gimp 2?

Tags: gimp, alignment

How can I perfectly justify text in GIMP 2. I tried but the result is this. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hi, I select the text and then click the Justify button. Thanks!

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "perfectly" and "justify". From what I can see, the text is already justified (aligned to both the left and right margins). How is it that you would like the text to appear?

Comment: Perhaps you need a **hyphenation** in order to reduce the spaces, but afaik GIMP doesn't support it. You can also arrange the text in a wordprocessor (Word, LibreOffice), export it as a PDF (so that the quality of the text is maintained), import it in GIMP.

Comment: First, ensure there are no double spaces in your text. Ensure there are no "hard" spaces. Use one space character between words. Use one space character between sentences. Only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is justified correctly.  The problem is that you have lengthy words and a narrow text box.  It's already putting as many words as it can fit on each line.

educational = 11 chars
organizations = 13 chars

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I also think Gimp has done its job right. However ,my boss still does not like the awkward spaces as in the picture. He asked me to find a way.  I heard Publisher of Microsoft Office can do perfect justify by automatic tracking and kerning. Can we do the same in Gimp? Is there any plugin that can do it? Nice weekend!

Comment: @HuyThan - That's an interesting question too!  I've never looked for plugins for gimp that assist in text formatting like that.

Comment: For plug-ins to help with that, a more sophisticated text-layer API would be needed. If you need this amount of control over text layout and want to stick to Free Software, I'd suggest to give Scribus a try.

Comment: Thanks for the inside scoop on that @MichaelSchumacher . As an outsider, it seems possible, but I don't have the chops like you to say what's on the inside :)

Answer (score 1):

Kerning each line produces excellent results. When you make the text layer active, the box above the text where you specify the font has two numbers on the lower right to change the text baseline and kerning. Separately for each line, select the line and adjust the kerning so that all of the lines have the exact same length. This gives it the look of old-fashioned typesetting - much better than a "justify" function which simply spreads the words out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manual kerning, which does look nice if done well (-- but I fear your gaps are too wide --), you could try hyphenate some of the words. This text does not appear to aim at children, so it is probably appropriate for your readers to read hyphenated words.

If you are unsure about hyphenation rules in English, use one of the many free tools available or check a good dictionary. One possibility:
https://www.hyphenation24.com/

Also think about hanging punctuation, once you have some dashes at the right side... :-)